Error with Canopy size creating Merkle tree with bubblegum program
I am trying to create a merkle tree wth MPL Bubbegum but I am running into this error

# ------ snip

  program: {
    name: 'mplBubblegum',
    publicKey: 'BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY',
    getErrorFromCode: [Function: getErrorFromCode],
    getErrorFromName: [Function: getErrorFromName],
    isOnCluster: [Function: isOnCluster]
  },
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: CreateTree',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program log: AnchorError thrown in program/src/processor/create_tree.rs:99. Error Code: InvalidCanopySize. Error Number: 6041. Error Message: Canopy size should be set bigger for this tree.',
    'Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY consumed 14435 of 399850 compute units',
    'Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY failed: custom program error: 0x1799'
  ],
  code: 6041
}

I encounter the error after a maxDepth of 14 and a maxBufferSize of 2048

https://compressed.app/
